# Test rendering views with EJS in Mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, ejs

I have finished building a CRUD application with 20 tests passing. I am using EJS to render the views and now I am having a problem with my tests.

As a simple example let's say that I was checking to see that when a GET request is sent to `'/'` that a JSON would be sent like so `res.json({message:'hello'})` so I could set up my tests in Mocha so that res.body.message equates to 'hello'.

However what if I wanted to render the `index.ejs` page instead of sending a JSON. So it would look like `res.render('index',{message:'hello'})`. How can I test `res.render()`? or more specifically how can I test the object passed to `res.render()`?

**EDIT:** The solution to this problem (and problems of this sort) can be solved by using a testing paradigm called **FUNCTIONAL TESTING**. Google it.

Answer (score 2):

To test a http *get* essentially can be understood as a need to test a route.
So, your test should include a expect clause (as to what to expect when the route is sought) and the response to validate, in this case a JSON object.

Using Mocha, you can describe the test as

```
 it('should respond with JSON data', function (done) {
  request(server)
    .get('/about/jv')
    .expect(200)
    .end(function (err, response) {
      assert.equal(response.header['content-type'], 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
      assert.deepEqual(response.body, {
        "data":{
        "username":"hello"}
      });
      done();
    });
});
```

Because you need a server to run a http request against, 'supertest', a node package is used to start your 'server.js' to initialize the server and test with request(server).

Check [this](https://github.com/ravichandranjv/UnitTestingNodeJSRoute) - The GitHub repo has the complete test template for this requirement. It has a test for the returned JSON object as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16596394)

Comment: Thanks, Patrick! The EDIT part of the question somehow diminished my enthusiasm to answer fully and I was not sure if the questioner is really looking for an answer but since others may land up on the question with a similar requirement, I provided the link.

Comment: @PatrickHund If my Edit satisfies your review concern, please remove the -1 downvote